# If $x$ is real number and $x \in \mathbb T$ is then $x^n \in \mathbb T$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Here $\mathbb T$ stands for the set of real transcendental numbers.

Comment: Please use $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb A$

Comment: @KennyLau No i will not, because I also use $\mathbb I$ for $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$. We have to have a letter for the set of transcendentals, but I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x^n \in \Bbb A$, then $p(x^n)=0$ for some polynomial $p$ with integer coefficients. Define $f(x)=p(x^n)$. Then, $f$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, with root $x$.